# Alert message if data is existed in MS ACCESS DB using c#

Tags: c#, ms-access-2007

```
OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand("select * from patient_det", con);
int count = (int)cmd1.ExecuteScalar();
if (count > 0)
{ 
   Response.Write("<script>alert('Data Existed!!')</script>");
}
else
{  
    OleDbCommand cmd2 = new OleDbCommand("insert into patient_det values('" + st1 + "' , '" + i1 + "' , '" + i2 + "' , '" + i3 + "' , '" + p1 + "')", con);
    cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
    int temp = cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
    Response.Write("<script>alert('Registered Successfully!!')</script>");
}
```

This code shows error like

> Specified cast is not valid

How to fix it?

Comment: For which line the error is shown? Please edit your question!

Comment: What is the first column type that `select * from patient_det` returns? Looks like it is not integer. You should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) by the way. This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Comment: all column types sre TEXT.. i couldn't get which line makes error.

Comment: @Lucy If all columns are `TEXT`, how do you expect that explicitly cast one of your column to `int` on `int count = (int)cmd1.ExecuteScalar()` line? That does not make sense.

Comment: oh okay.what can i use instead of int count = (int)cmd1.ExecuteScalar()? I am new to this.

Comment: @Sonar i set indexed as no duplicates. It works fine. but i could not show error message. plz guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found Solution for this Question.

```
    int Count;
    con.Open();
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM TABLENAME WHERE   COLUMNNAME= '" + TXT1.Text + "'", con);
        OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(dt);
        if (dt.Rows.Count == 0)
        {
//Insert Query
           Response.Write("<script>alert('Added Successfully!!')</script>");
         }else
         {
            Response.Write("<script>alert('Data is Exist!!')</script>");

        }
```

Comment: Yes, you *could* do it that way, but it would be much more efficient to just do `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLENAME WHERE ...` and then use `ExecuteScalar()` to check if the row count was zero.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably in the line:

```
int count = (int)cmd1.ExecuteScalar();
```

This is the signature of ExecuteScalar:

```
public override object ExecuteScalar()
```

The query "select * from patient_det" using ExecuteScalar will return the element on the first column of the first row of the table so the DataType returned will be the one of the table.

Comment: The problem _probably_ on that line but that's not the point. `ExecuteScalar` returns `object` but since `TEXT` type mapped with `string` on CLR side, there is no explicit conversation from `string` to `int`. That's why OP gets: _Specified cast is not valid_.

Comment: @Robert thanq.Now only i got the meaning of ExecuteScalar .but in my table second column name is Username.if the username exist i wanna show error message.can i use select * from patient_det" query.If so how to check next line.?

Comment: OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand("select pat_name from pat_det", con);  OleDbDataReader da1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader(); is it correct? how to proceed next? pls help